# Integrating getlocations with facet api

Tags: search

I am using getlocations fields to get the user to fill his location and now I want to display a facet based on the city which we get from the getlocations fields and also I want to display the name which we get from getlocations fields as a sub-facet for the corresponding city but I am unable to do it. Can you help me?